# React, why to use Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, redux, frontend

It's been a while since I developed a front end with React and Redux. Is the Redux still relevant asset in React development? What are the benefits of Redux to just using React component state, props and lifecycle hooks without global state like Redux? For me, the global state smells like an anti pattern and not very functional.

Also, what is the best way to get a React project bootstrapped, including most reliable components for routing and REST connectivity?

Answer (score 3):

Still very relevant. Ask yourself "is managing state getting too complicated and I have to pass state through components that don't use it way too much?" If so, use redux. No? No need for it.

Benefits are that it simplifies code and dealing with passing state.

Answer (score 2):

Redux is still relevant but some use cases have been replaced.

## Use case: caching HTTP responses

We can now use the [ReactJS Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). For those using GraphQL, the [Apollo client does some caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html) as well.

## Use case: having to pass state down through intermediate components

Again, we now prefer to use the ReactJS Context API for this.

## Global vs. Local state

In [ReasonML](https://reasonml.github.io/) / [ReasonReact](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/en/), the future of ReactJS, [reducers are built into components](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/state-actions-reducer), but at the component level. There's no global state by default.

Redux is basically a JavaScript implementation of the [Elm architecture](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/), which does use global state (and is certainly functional).

## Testability

For me, the reason to use Redux is testability.

> Because most of the Redux code you write are functions, and many of them are pure, they are easy to test without mocking.

[source](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writingtests)

## Bootstrapping

Facebook just released `create-react-app` version 2.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases

Check it out!

## Routing

Use [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

## REST

GraphQL is quite popular among the ReactJS community. The TL;DR is that at the heart of React is the ability to colocate all of a components markup, styles and behavior. With GraphQL, we can colocate a component's data as well. There was an excellent talk on this topic by [Chris Toomey](https://twitter.com/christoomey?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) at the recent ReactBoston conference that will be coming to Youtube in the next week or two.

If you want to use REST, you can use the Context API to cache any responses.

Answer (score 0):

**1st benefit:** with Redux - you can access the state from every component in your app.
without Redux you need to chain the state as props from parent to children, the problem is too much chaining, its hard to understand the code.
for example:

```js
//Trying to pass the state of FirstComponent as props to ThirdComponent

class FirstComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        firstComponentState: 'some value'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SecondComponent 
                firstComponentState={firstComponentState}
            />
        )
    }
}


const SecondComponent = (props) => (
        <ThirdComponent 
            firstComponentState={props.firstComponentState}
        />
)

const ThirdComponent = (props) => (
    <div>{props.firstComponentState}</div>
)
```

If the ThirdComponent needs access to the state of the FirstComponent - we need to chain the state from parent to children until it reaches the wanted component. now how our code will look like if we needed to chain the state 10 levels down? it will be very hard to understand. 
but with Redux - all we need to do is connect the ThirdComponent to the global redux state and use it.

**2nd benefit:* Passing state between siblings. 
consider this code:

```js
//Trying to pass the state of FirstSibling to SecondSibling

const Parent = () => (
    <div>
        <FirstSibling/>
        <SecondSibling/>
    </div>
)

class FirstSibling extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: 'pass me to SecondSibling'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Something..</div>
        )
    }
}

const SecondSibling = () => (
    <div>I need the state of FirstSibling</div>
)
```

Without Redux how can we pass the state of FirstSibling component to SecondSibling component? 
for that we need to pass the state one level up - from FirstSibling to Parent and from Parent we need to chain it down to SecondSibling. 
its not best practice to chain props from children to parent. 
Now imagine that FirstSibling and SecondSibling have children and we want to pass the state between them - the code is becoming unreadable.
but again, with Redux - all we need to do is connect that wanted component to the global state and fetch data directly.